# How to fit this data to be used in NIntegrate later?

Tags: fitting, interpolation, data

I have a list of data points that resemble a chi-squared distribution (long tailed gaussian) that I am having trouble fitting or finding an equation with. The goal is to use the fitted equation in an NIntegrate routine. Things I've tried:

1. I tried fitting the FWHM of the peak to the FWHM of a gaussian, which is easy to describe mathematically. But, unfortunately this resulted in poor accuracy.
2. I tried using the Interpolation function of mathematica. This seemed to work well but I get an error when I try to integrate beyond the domain of the interpolated function. Also I am wary of it accuracy.

So, finally I am wondering if any of you mathematica ninjas have some idea of how I could possible fit this data and have an equation/expression that I could later include in an NIntegrate routine that will preserve accuracy! The data is located below thanks a bunch!!!!

[image]

```
{{-0.00146513, 0.}, {-0.00143553, 0.}, {-0.00140593, 
  0.}, {-0.00137633, 0.}, {-0.00134673, 0.}, {-0.00131714, 
  0.}, {-0.00128754, 0.}, {-0.00125794, 0.}, {-0.00122834, 
  0.709003}, {-0.00119874, 3.34244}, {-0.00116914, 
  9.62218}, {-0.00113954, 29.4743}, {-0.00110995, 
  59.3537}, {-0.00108035, 91.2588}, {-0.00105075, 
  123.974}, {-0.00102115, 125.899}, {-0.000991552, 
  104.932}, {-0.000961953, 88.2202}, {-0.000932355, 
  64.2154}, {-0.000902756, 52.4662}, {-0.000873158, 
  37.9823}, {-0.000843559, 31.6013}, {-0.000813961, 
  26.3344}, {-0.000784362, 24.8151}, {-0.000754763, 
  17.6238}, {-0.000725165, 16.8135}, {-0.000695566, 
  13.8762}, {-0.000665968, 11.5466}, {-0.000636369, 
  10.9389}, {-0.000606771, 9.31833}, {-0.000577172, 
  7.39389}, {-0.000547573, 5.97588}, {-0.000517975, 
  4.76045}, {-0.000488376, 4.65916}, {-0.000458778, 
  4.15273}, {-0.000429179, 4.15273}, {-0.000399581, 
  2.9373}, {-0.000369982, 2.53215}, {-0.000340383, 
  2.53215}, {-0.000310785, 2.32958}, {-0.000281186, 
  1.51929}, {-0.000251588, 1.62058}, {-0.000221989, 
  1.31672}, {-0.000192391, 0.709003}, {-0.000162792, 
  0.709003}, {-0.000133194, 0.607717}, {-0.000103595, 
  1.41801}, {-0.0000739964, 0.911575}, {-0.0000443978, 
  0.405145}, {-0.0000147993, 0.709003}, {0.0000147993, 
  0.506431}, {0.0000443978, 0.506431}, {0.0000739964, 
  0.709003}, {0.000103595, 0.405145}, {0.000133194, 
  0.405145}, {0.000162792, 0.101286}, {0.000192391, 
  0.607717}, {0.000221989, 0.303858}, {0.000251588, 
  0.810289}, {0.000281186, 0.405145}, {0.000310785, 
  0.607717}, {0.000340383, 0.303858}, {0.000369982, 
  0.303858}, {0.000399581, 0.101286}, {0.000429179, 0.}, {0.000458778,
  0.101286}, {0.000488376, 0.101286}, {0.000517975, 
  0.}, {0.000547573, 0.}, {0.000577172, 0.}, {0.000606771, 
  0.202572}, {0.000636369, 0.}, {0.000665968, 0.}, {0.000695566, 
  0.101286}, {0.000725165, 0.101286}, {0.000754763, 
  0.101286}, {0.000784362, 0.101286}, {0.000813961, 0.}, {0.000843559,
  0.101286}, {0.000873158, 0.}, {0.000902756, 0.}, {0.000932355, 
  0.}, {0.000961953, 0.}, {0.000991552, 0.}, {0.00102115, 
  0.}, {0.00105075, 0.}, {0.00108035, 0.}, {0.00110995, 
  0.}, {0.00113954, 0.}, {0.00116914, 0.101286}, {0.00119874, 
  0.}, {0.00122834, 0.101286}, {0.00125794, 0.}, {0.00128754, 
  0.}, {0.00131714, 0.}, {0.00134673, 0.}, {0.00137633, 
  0.}, {0.00140593, 0.}, {0.00143553, 0.}, {0.00146513, 0.}}
```

Comment: I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You've been using the site for 8 months now. You already asked 14 questions but never voted and never accepted an answer. It's time to participate more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is enough for you:

```
d1 = Transpose[{#[[1]] - #[[1, 1]], #[[2]]} &@ Transpose@Select[data, #[[2]] > 0 &]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[d1, c PDF[BetaDistribution[3, b], x], {b, c},  x];
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, .003}, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> Point@d1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another option:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[d1, c PDF[MoyalDistribution[.0002, b], x], {b, c}, x]
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, .003}, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> Point@d1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hmmm, these are great but is there a genralized routine, for let's say other data sets? When I tried these methods with my other data sets I got poorly fitted results. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @user1886681 fitting is an art, not an automatic procedure. If you really need something more automatic you'll need to switch to something like this http://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/